# How do I check for integer and range at the same time in python?

Tags: python

```
base_pay = None
while True:
    try:
        base_pay = int(input(">>> "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Numbers only please")
```

How do i check for a range between 800 and 1500? I know I can use the `if`, but I can't combine it both together:

```
if not (800 <= base_pay <= 1500):
    print("Please enter a value between 800 and 1500")
    continue
```

Comment: Would `if 800 <= base_pay <= 1500: break` inside the `while` loop do what you want? Your question is a little unclear.

Comment: `if not (800 <= base_pay <= 1500):` should work

Answer (score 2):

> i cant combine it both together

Sure you can. There are lots of possible solutions, here's one:

```
#UNTESTED
base_pay = None
while True:
    try:
        base_pay = int(input(">>> "))
        if 800 <= base_pay <= 1500:
            break

        print("Please enter a value between 800 and 1500")
    except ValueError:
        print("Numbers only please")
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if i understand your question... but maybe

```
if user_inputted_string.isdigit() and 800 <= int(user_inputted_string) <= 1500:
   print("You Need To Put an int between 800,1500 ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if not(base_pay <= 1500 and base_pay >= 800):
    print("Please enter a value between 800 and 1500")
    continue
```